# Fatal Python error when attempting to upgrade pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I'm trying to upgrade pip to version 8.0.2 from version 7.1.2, however, when I type `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, into the command line, it returns:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007cf8 (most recent call first):
```

My `pip --version` returns:

```
pip 7.1.2 from C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages (python 3.5)
```

I'm running Windows 10, 64-bit operating system.

EDIT: Additionally, when I type only `python` in command line, it returns:

```
C:\Users\Owner>python
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007cf8 (most recent call first):
```

And python "stops working."

---

EDIT 2: My PATH:

> PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Python332\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
>   2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Python334\Tools\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\Library\bin

---

I do have multiple versions of python installed, I realize that could contribute to the problem, but if it actually does or what to do about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `python3` instead.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Edit:

To temporary fix the problem with your PATH enter the following commands:

```
C:\>set PATH=C:\Program Files\Python 3.5;%PATH%
C:\>set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib
C:\>python
```

You should change the `C:\My_python_lib` to something similar for your system.

This is temporary and after the current session everything will be reset. To find more about this, have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables).

From [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip) source to upgrade `pip` for Windows, the following should work:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Comment: This returns `'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Can you update your questions and include your operating system as well?

Comment: Updated, has that helped?

Comment: When you type `python` in your command prompt, what is the python's interpreter version ?

Comment: Unforunately, using `py -3` brings me back to where I started: pip version 7.1.2 installing successfully and it giving me a recommendation to use `python -m pip install` if I want to upgrade to 8.0.2. Originally, I used `pip install --upgrade pip`, though.

Comment: I have found the following command on official documentation, `python -m pip install -U pip` (I am sorry, not Windows user, so please try and let me know)

Answer (score 2):

**The Correct Answer**

Okay, so helped by Rafael, I got this to work. What he found was that I needed to update the contents of my PATH with the location of python 3.5. Also, I had to create a new user variable called PYTHONPATH, which was directed to my `libs` directory.

You can see how to the menu required for this here: [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)